# number format Exception for input string to integer

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to receive message using socket
When Executing this code i am getting NumberFormatException

```
public class ThreadSocket extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
    int k;

    ThreadSocket(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String message = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Incomming message client : " + message);
                k += Integer.parseInt(message);
                System.out.println("la somme est :" + k);
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This Exception :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3 : 2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at ThreadSocket.run(ThreadSocket.java:33)
```

Comment: So the message received appears to be `3 : 2`. I cannot tell from your question whether that was intended or not, but you are trying tp convert is to an integer. You cannot do that. You only can of the string conforms to the syntax of an integer, like `4`, `+23463` or `-2034284621`.

Comment: You may want to tell us the desired behaviour and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Incomming message client : user : +30
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "user : +30"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at ThreadSocket.run(ThreadSocket.java:33)

Comment: i have server and multi client i want to get operation ADDITION if i send msg number i have this msg

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Yeah, but if I am right in assuming the client has sent `3 : 2` — then what?

Comment: nooo client sent 2  the name of client is 3 :D

Comment: Alright, so you want to take the `2` out of the message `3 : 2` and add it, the 2, to `k` — have I got it right?

Comment: YES my friend .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not quite sure what the possible messages received on the socket are. The following will accept messages on the form `client : number` as well as messages containing only the number. Decide if this is what you need.

```
        while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Incomming message client : " + message);
            // is there a colon followed by a space in the message?
            final String delimiter = ": ";
            int indexOfColon = message.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
            if (indexOfColon == -1) { // no, no colon and space in message
                // try to use entire message
                k += Integer.parseInt(message);
            } else { // yes
                // take out the part after the colon and space and try parsing it as an integer
                int number = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(indexOfColon + delimiter.length()));
                k += number;
            }
            System.out.println("la somme est :" + k);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the numbers of your input String one by one.
and Then you can divide them.

Comment: it is better to post this type of answers, as a comment

Comment: Posting a comment requires a certain reputation. So user7217438 cannot do that.